# Python: "re" module is included in "Tkinter" module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, conda, miniconda

I'm using **Python 3.6.4** with **Miniconda** on **MacOS**. I'm curious about that I can use methods that belongs to `re` module after I import `tkinter`. For example, if I want to use a `re` method without importing it:

```
>>> re.compile('abc')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 're' is not defined
```

But if I use a `re` methods after importing `tkinter`, it works properly, like:

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> re.compile('abc')
re.compile('abc')
```

So I can use `re.compile()` even if I haven't done `import re`. Why does it happen?

Comment: Because tkinter presumably has a `import re` and when you do `from tkinter import *` you're pulling `re` into scope as though you'd done `import re` directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the tkinter Source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py) in line 39:

```
import re
```

So when you import the Module tkinter you automaticly import re with it

Comment: No, only when you explicitly do `from tkinter import *` and this kind of weird side effect is precisely one of the reasons you shouldn't.